# Handle event for html button codename one

Tags: codenameone

In form I embedded WebBrowser component with lots of html contents (Mainly Table, buttons ) for rich ui. Is it possible to handle event on clicking html button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, look at the kitchen sink demo for a sample.

Generally just navigate to a URL on the event and implement your own `BrowserNavigationCallback` to handle navigation to that specific URL.

This is the code from the Kitchen Sink demo notice the `setBrowserNavigationCallback` block:

```
    final WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    if(wb.getInternal() instanceof BrowserComponent) {
        Button btn = new Button("Add");
        final TextArea content = new TextArea();
        Container north = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        north.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);
        north.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, btn);
        cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, north);
        content.setHint("Add to web document");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).execute("fnc('" + content.getText() + "');");
            }
        });
        ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback() {
            public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
                if(url.startsWith("http://sayhello")) {
                    // warning!!! This is not on the EDT and this method MUST return immediately!
                    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).execute("fnc('this was written by Java code!')");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```